# How to limit Icon/Textlabel density in Mapbox Studio / Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, postgis, mapbox-gl-js

So my problem is, that I have a tileset which geometries are Multipolygons and when I want to display the district names it places multiple labels instead of just one centered. Is there a way to fix this?

[Here is a screenshot for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCt2y.png)

The data comes from a postgis database, I just export it to a CSV and upload it to mapbox.

I have tried converting the Multipolygon into single Polygons but that ended in the same result.

I also played around with the text padding in mapbox studio but with this option the label placement is very off.

Is there possibly a way trough Mapbox GL JS to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a separate label layer. You can use [geojson-polygon-labels](https://github.com/andrewharvey/geojson-polygon-labels) to do this.